# Get timezone by Country and State/Province in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Is there a way to retrieve timezone information based on **Country and State/Province** in Python?

E.g. The United States and New York will get EST (Eastern Standard Time).

If that's not possible or efficient, is there a way to get timezone based on **Country and City** instead?

I'm using Python Django in my project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you with what you are trying to do:

```
# importing module

    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
    from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

  
# initialize Nominatim API
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
  
# input as a geek
lad = "Dhaka"
print("Location address:", lad)
  
# getting Latitude and Longitude
location = geolocator.geocode(lad)
  
print("Latitude and Longitude of the said address:")
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
  
# pass the Latitude and Longitude
# into a timezone_at
# and it return timezone
obj = TimezoneFinder()
  
# returns 'Europe/Berlin'
result = obj.timezone_at(lng=location.longitude, lat=location.latitude)
print("Time Zone : ", result)
```

I got it from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-time-zone-of-a-given-location-using-python/

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pytz` library and use the code below:

for example, to get the US Central Time you must pass the `pytz.timezone('US/Central')` to the `datetime`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# For Example US/Central timezone datetime
aware_us_central = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Central'))
print('US Central DateTime', aware_us_central)
```

Comment: I need to get timezone FROM country and city